# Swift 2.0: Type of Expression is ambiguous without more context?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, avfoundation, xcode7

The following used to work in Swift 1.2:

```
var recordSettings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0]
```

Now, it gives the error:

> "Type expression is ambiguous without more context".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To comply to the required `[String : AnyObject]` format required by `recordSettings` parameter; In addition to @Unheilig's answer, you'll need to convert your `ints` and `floats` to `NSNumber`:

```
let recordSettings : [String : AnyObject] =
[
    AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue as NSNumber,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000 as NSNumber,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2 as NSNumber,
    AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0 as NSNumber
]
```

Comment: I agree except I didn't ask the question correctly. @Stephan answered the question I meant to ask.

Answer (score 57):

You could give the compiler more information:

```
let recordSettings : [String : Any] =
[
    AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I didn't Know Any was available. I was trying AnyObject and that didn't work. Sadly the receiver of recordSettings requires [String : AnyObject]

Comment: @lernerbot, see my answer below.

Comment: Hi Unheilig, Can you please check my question i have same issue? Thanks  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279942/type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-more-context-swift-2-0`

Answer (score 4):

I also got this error message trying to initialise an array of optionals with nil:

```
var eggs : [Egg] = Array<Egg>(count: 10, repeatedValue: nil)
```

> Expression Type 'Array<Egg>' is ambiguous without more context.

Changing `[Egg]` to `[Egg?]` fixed the error.