# .Failure(error)! ambiguous without more context

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to run some code from Hillegass's Cocoa Programming for OS X textbook, but my version of Swift and Xcode are newer than those in the book. Not 100% sure that's what's causing the problem, but it's my guess. Whether or not that's the case, I don't know how to fix it.

Code snippet:

```
enum FetchCoursesResult
{
    case Success([ Course])
    case Failure(NSError)
}


func fetchCoursesUsingCompletionHandler( completionHandler: (FetchCoursesResult) -> (Void))
{
    let url = NSURL( string: "http:// bookapi.bignerdranch.com/ courses.json")!
    let request = NSURLRequest( URL: url)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest( request, completionHandler:
    {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        var result: FetchCoursesResult

        if data == nil
        {
            result = .Failure(error)!
        }
        else
        {
            print(" Received \( data!.length) bytes.")
            result = .Success([]) // Empty array until parsing is added
        }

        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock(
        {
            completionHandler( result)
        })
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Xcode gives me an error on ".Failure(error)!" and says "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context."

I've seen a lot of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663364/swift-2-0-type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-more-context) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211809/error-type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-more-context) asking about this error message but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case (the solutions proposed to this error always seem to differ). What context does it need here exactly? I presume it has something to do with the enum but I'm not sure what.

Comment: You need to unwrap the error. Though changing `result = .Failure(error)!` to `result = .Failure(error!)` should fix the issue. That's because the associated value of your `error` case expects a non optional value. Hope this helps.

Comment: That seems to have done it, thank you!